# Use of the "OR" Regex operator with the find command

Tags: regex, find

There are so many of these questions on the net, but I was unable to solve this simple problem.

I have a directory with a lot of images, but I only want to copy a subset of them identified by ranges of numbers. Each picture has the format: "`[random characters][capture number].BMP`"

For example: `IZ000561.BMP`

I am using this in conjunction with `find` and the `-regex` option. 
The regular expression I thought to use was simple:

`.*(26[2-7]|27[0-2]).*`

if I wanted to match images with a tag of [262-267],[270-272]. This approach failed, however. I went to an online [Regex](http://regexr.com/3cj1r) tester and all matched as expected using this expression. It must be that `find`'s regex engine expects a different format for this kind of filtering.

The full command I was using:

`find /path/to/images/ -regex ".*(26[2-7]|27[0-2]).*" -exec echo {} \;`

What is a valid expression for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 12):

Reading into the man page of `find` gives a bit of useful information:

> The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs
>   Regular Expressions.

So, taking a look into the syntax of [Emacs Regex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)

[image]

It seems that all special characters are required to be escaped with `\`. Taking this into account, the expected results were obtained after changing the regular expression to the following:

```
find /path/to/images/ -regex ".*\(26[2-7]\|27[0-2]\).*" -exec echo {} \;
```

I consulted the man page before posting this question, but apparently not meticulously enough.

Answer (score 6):

I realise you posted your own answer, but in case you wish to use the REGEX syntax you are, you can change the REGEX type using this command:

`-regextype TYPE`

So I believe to make yours work:

`find /path/to/images/ -regextype sed -regex '.*(26[2-7]|27[0-2]).*' -exec echo {} \;`

may do the trick.

Also, just a note, your regex will match anything with 262-267 or 270-272 within. That means it'll catch `IZ262561.BMP`, as well as `IZ134267.JPG`, and `ASDNASDNOANFOIAJFOIJDIO000262.EXE` for example. I'm not sure what files you're working with, but you might need to narrow your regex down as it's quite loose on what it'll accept.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to make the expression more specific. The numbers are always followed by the `.BMP` extension, so that's a great way to do it. I noticed the argument to change the regex type, but there were no examples in the manual for using it, or valid *types* for use with this switch.Thanks!

Comment: I tried typing in an incorrect parameter using the `-regextype` option and, sure enough, `find` reported the supported options as: `findutils-default`, `awk`, `egrep`, `ed`, `emacs`, `gnu-awk`, `grep`, `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep`, `posix-extended`, `posix-minimal-basic`, `sed`.

Answer (score 6):

There also is an `-or` (or `-o`) operator to the `find` command. You could divide your expression in two subexpressions:

```
find /path/to/images/ -regex ".*(26[2-7]).*" -o -regex ".*(27[0-2]).*" -exec echo {} \;
```

`-o` is POSIX compliant, while `-or` is not:

As per the `find` man page:

> ```
>    expr1 -o expr2
>           Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
>
>    expr1 -or expr2
>           Same as expr1 -o expr2, but not POSIX compliant.
> ```

Comment: Man, you totally saved me from a lot of headache. Thank you!